# CSS animation: slide div in and out after x second

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to slide div in after 1 second and slide it out after 4 seconds exactly the same way. is it possible?

The second problem is, that the black div(second div), disappears after the animation.

```css
.first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.second {
  width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  animation-name: example2;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    margin-left: -200px
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0px
  }
}

@keyframes example2 {
  from {
    width: 0px
  }
  to {
    width: 250px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SUBnz/1267/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use percentages you can do what you want.
You can define your animation just as you like.

```
@keyframes example {
  0%, 100% {
    margin-left: -200px
  }
  10%, 90% {
    margin-left: 0px
  }
}
```

set the animation delay to 1s.
you need to experiment with the percentages for your need

---

The second div is going to its original state after the animation.
This will set the css stile after the animation is over

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Comment: great BO, thanks. off topic question, can i fire this animation up from jquery?

Comment: you can fire css animations only by assigning a class with a animation to an element. So yeah, if you add a class with an css animation to an element, it will work :)